Statistical test of ensemble averages
Machine learning models are evaluated by their predictions, producing a single-value score (e.g. mean squared error). Machine learning models are initialized randomly and that affects their score. Repeat modelling result in different scores. Typically practitioners take the best model and move on. But to reproduce the best performing model is based on randomness.
It is assumed that the average predictions of the models (i.e. an ensemble average) is more reproducible than a single best model.
I want to determine if a particular method improved the modelling performance. For each experimental unit, I have say 20 repeat models. I can take the ensemble average of the repeat models and then compare the scores. But these 20 repeats are also prone to randomness - different set of 20 repeats likely results in different ensemble average.
I want some statistical backing comparing the ensemble average. I can perform a Mann-Whitney U test to compare the performances of the sets of 20 repeats but this gives me a p-value comparing the performances individually.
Would it be appropriate to do ensemble averages of sub-sets of the models and the compare their performances? For a subset of n < N, we determine the performance of the ensemble average for all possible sub-sets.
If it is appropriate, is there a general guideline to determine the size of sub-set?
Any opinions on any part of this is welcome. Thank you!

The answer is bootstrap!
No need for sub-sets. You do a bootstrap of the 20 repeats and determine the ensemble performance.


I want to determine if a particular method improved the modelling performance. For each experimental unit, I have say 20 repeat models. I can take the ensemble average of the repeat models and then compare the scores. But these 20 repeats are also prone to randomness - different set of 20 repeats likely results in different ensemble average.

This problem is true of almost all analyses.
Let's say I want to compare the weights of people on two different diets.
I can take a sample of 20 people on diet A, and 20 people on diet B,
and compare the scores using an independant samples t-test.
But the weight measurement for each person is prone to randomness, in this case because a person's weight fluctuates throughout the day (or obvious reasons), and because household weighing scales are not totally reliable.
These two sources of variance - variance between people, and variance when measuring a single person's weight combine in our data, and the variance of the data is the sum of the variance of these two individual factors. Fortunately, this is accounted for by any statistical test you care to use.
This is the long way of saying that this isn't an issue, and a t-test is fine here.
